# how can i select data and sub query group by

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i select data only show first `lot` data . but i need all `lot` data.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT lot,
(select count(pass) FROM pass_fail_result where pass=0) toatl_fail,
(select count(pass) FROM pass_fail_result where pass=1) toatl_pass FROM pass_fail_result group by lot;
```

I want to show all pass result like `pass=10` and `fail=2`
[image]

Comment: add group by lot in your sub query also right now your sub query is give your multiple records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via conditional aggregation, where we count or sum `CASE` expressions which target the failing or passing records:

```
SELECT
    lot,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pass = 0 THEN 1 END) AS toatl_fail,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pass = 1 THEN 1 END) AS toatl_pass
FROM pass_fail_result
GROUP BY
    lot;
```